# Do sweat pores change diameter?

Tags: skin, allergies, heat

In [Cholinergic Urticaria](http://www.cholinergicurticaria.net/cholinergic-urticaria-causes-what-causes-cholinergic-urticaria-to-develop/), some people believe that the itching which is generally more in winters might be because that the diameter of sweat pores is less due to less activity(less sweat production) and in summers the diameter is usually more due to high activity (more sweat production).

**Question:** Hence the question in general, **Do sweat pores change diameter?**

Comment: Personal medical questions are off-topic here at SE.Biology. This question is legit and well written but please remove any link to yourself. Thank you.

Comment: I edited your question so that it might not get closed. Please revert of modify my changes as you like.

Comment: gud one @cagliari2005

Comment: what is your question? Why it happens more in winter than in summer? Or what the causes are?

Comment: I think I included the causes as far as researchers know today in my question,but if you wanna go more into detail into causes then fine.... @AliceD plz make sure its focus is on my question in **bold**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pores don't change size; that is, the diameter of pore does not increase or decrease in hot or cold environments. Your skin, where pores are located, is not muscle but an organ so the pores don't contract or expand.

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin#/media/File:Skin.png]

Pores can become clogged with dirt, oil, and debris (make up). When pores are clogged, you are more inclined to notice which would cause the illusion that the pore is bigger.

> It's important to know that you can't actually "shrink" your pores. They're nothing but small openings in the skin -- because they don't have muscles, they can't open or close. So although you can't physically change the structure of your pores by making them smaller, there are things that you can do to minimize their appearance[$^1$](http://health.howstuffworks.com/skin-care/problems/treating/shrink-large-pores.htm).

Comment: Just learned something.

Comment: @cagliari2005 it is actually common that people think pores expand and contract. The reason is because washing with warm water loosens debris cleaning the pores. Therefore, people then think the pores expanded when it was just warm water loosen the gunk.